# How to display all elements of an array list in my frame

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my code and when I run it, only the tile 'd' appears. I was wondering why when I run it in Java, only one tile appears and how to make it so they all appear? All answers are appreciated.

```
 package code;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import java.awt.Component;
 import java.awt.LayoutManager;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;    
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
 import javax.swing.JButton;



public class Game implements Runnable {
static final int width = 300;
static final int height = 500;


@Override
public void run(){

    JFrame f = new JFrame("KeyBricks Game");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    f.setSize(width,height);
    p.setVisible(true);
    f.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    Tile A = new Tile('a');
    Tile B = new Tile('b');
    Tile C = new Tile('c');
    Tile D = new Tile('d');
    ArrayList<Tile> tile = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    tile.add(A);
    tile.add(B);
    tile.add(C);
    tile.add(D);
    for(int i=0; i < tile.size(); i++){
        JButton j = new JButton("" + tile.get(i).getChar());
        f.add(j);   
    }


        }
```

Comment: f.add(new JButton(""+tile.get(i).getChar())); Should work...

Comment: Move pack and setVisible to the end of the method, calling it last

Comment: Also change f.add to p.add

Comment: One of the problems is the you're adding each button to the JFrame, which is using a BorderLayout, so only the last button is been managed by the layout. Instead, you should be adding the buttons to the JPanle, which is using a GridLayout

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an uppercase character. Most of your names are correct, but some are not. Be consistent.

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer.

Comment: The class name is "Game", hmmm is it a 3D game ?